# Pandas DataFrame groupby-specific filters based on aggregate stats

Tags: python, pandas

Having a large dataframe like this:

```
runs = 100
rows = runs * 20
run_index = sum([[n] * 20 for n in range(runs)], [])
color = sum([sum([[n] * 5 for n in range(4)], []) for each in range(runs)], [])
size = sum([sum([range(5) for each in range(4)], []) for each in range(runs)], [])
value1 = [np.random.random() for each in range(rows)]
value2 = [np.random.random() for each in range(rows)]
value3 = [np.random.random() for each in range(rows)]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(run_index, color, size, value1, value1, value1), columns=['run', 'color', 'size', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'])
```

How can I achieve the following filter: 
Essentially, exclude every such run, where at least one value{1,2,3} is lower than the 10th percentile (or any other stat) of given value within the given (color:size) category across all runs.

```
runs_to_exclude = set()
value_names = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
aggregate_stats = df.groupby(['color', 'size'])[value_names].describe(percentiles=[0.05])
for run, run_group in df.groupby('run'):
    for index, row in run_group.iterrows():
        row_color = row['color']
        row_size = row['size']
        for value_name in value_names:
            if row[value_name] < aggregate_stats.loc[row_color, row_size, '5%'][value_name]:
                runs_to_exclude.add(run)
                break
```

Doing it in for loops is very slow with large dataframes and obviously not the way to go with Pandas. 
How can I do something like this with efficient pandas? 
The groupby().filter(filter_function) scheme appears to be only able to work with constants

Comment: you've got a typo in your sample code - it throws a `TypeError` on the size invocation

Comment: ah, python 3 issue, nm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your stat aggregation a little, bit, so that it only contains the values you want to check against:

```
aggregate_stats = df.groupby(['color', 'size'])[value_names].\
                     describe(percentiles=[0.05])
fifth_p = aggregate_stats.reset_index().\
                          loc[aggregate_stats.reset_index().level_2 == '5%',
                              ['color', 'size',
                               'value1', 'value2', 'value3']].\
                          set_index(['color', 'size'])
```

(Perhaps unnecessary?)

Assuming you keep the indices matched up, you can now subtract the data frames directly - the indices should keep them in line.

```
run_to_check = 0
checker = df.loc[df.run == run_to_check,
                 ['color', 'size',
                  'value1', 'value2', 'value3']].\
             set_index(['color','size']) < fifth_p
if checker.sum().sum() > 0:
    # Some fifth_p value was greater than a df value
    # run is bad
else:
    # run is fine
```

Comment: Interesting! Thank you! If I wanted to do that check against more values, would something like this be the best way?

`df_reindexed = df.loc[df.run == run_to_check, ['color', 'size', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3']].set_index(['color','size'])`

and then:

`checker = (df_reindexed < aggregate_stats.xs('10%', level=2)) & (df_reindexed > aggregate_stats.xs('90%', level=2))`

Comment: Conceptually that looks fine to me, but I'd test it.